# Прузи, пружина и прыгать — этимологически однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Относятся ли слова прузи, пружина и прыгать к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы имеете  в виду прузи  -  мн.ч. от пруг (южный диалект прус) - вид саранчи,( ст.-слав. прѫгъ"саранча"; см. Преобр. II, 139), то вполне возможно, ведь саранча прыгает, пружиня. Но в академической науке об этом нигде прямо не говорится, видимо, пока нет общего мнения.

Даже насчёт "пружина" и "прыгать" нет общего мнения.

Слово пружина все характеризуют как общеслав. суф. производное от пруга (*prǫga) , однокоренное с "упругий".2004  http://my-dict.ru/dic/etimologicheskiy-slovar-russkogo-yazyka/1374550-pruzhina

Семёнов возводит прыгать к общеславянскому  pryg.

> В древнерусских и старославянских памятниках литературы глагол
>   «прыгать» обнаружен не был. Это слово является только русским, т.к. в
>   других славянских языках для обозначения стремительного отталкивания
>   ногами от опоры используется глагол «скакать». Исследователи русского
>   языка предполагают, что от глагола «прыгать» могло произойти слово
>   «пружина» (или наоборот), поскольку оба слова имеют один и тот же
>   индоевропейский корень.Производные: прыгнуть, прыжок, прыгун.

http://www.terminy.info/russian-language/etymological-dictionary-of-the-russian-language-semenova/prygat

Шанский (вслед за Фасмером) пишет:

> Упругий - искон. преф. производное (с усилительным у-) от утраченного
>   пругыи, того же корня, что диал. пруга «пружина», сербохоров. пруг
>   «растянутый», чешск. pruh «полоса», нем. springen «прыгать». См.
>   пружина, запрячь.

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004   http://endic.ru/rusethy/Uprugi-4894.html

Мнение Крылова:

> Пружи́на. Общеславянское слово, образованное от существительного пруга
>   — «пружина», восходящего к той же основе, что и впрягать, упругий.
>   Отметим и родственное английское spring — «пружина».

https://krylov.lexicography.online/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

А вот Галина Цыганенко не считает слова прыгать и пружина однокоренными: пружина - от утраченного "пруга" (др-рус.глаг пругати (стрелять), пружитися - напрягаться), а "прыгать" - от утраченного сущ. прыгъ из праслав. prъgъ (ъ - ы)- скачок.

В любом случае, в далёком прошлом слова обозначали одно и то же - движение с напряжением.